# PS1 Command - Bash

Tags: bash, ps1

I am trying to get the PS1 command working with bash.

What I am trying to do is capture the user's data and input it to change the field on the command line.

I know the command is `PS1="MadMike"`, but what I am trying to do is the captured data from the read line and insert it into the command and then run the command

```
#PS1 Method
1)
echo -e "\n"
#Sub Menu for Method
echo "============================================"
echo "What would you like your command line to say"
echo "============================================"
echo -e "\n"
#Waiting for user input
echo "Type below"

#Capturing User input
read input
#Setting PS1 input
PS1="input:"
```

Comment: You mean you want to edit the `PS1` "environment variable"?

Comment: @midihenry: `$PS1` is a shell variable, not an environment variable (though you can export it to the environment if you like).

Comment: @KeithThompson Oups my bad. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the `$` sign to get the content of the `input` variable. It should be:

```
PS1="$input:"
```